# Unable to bump question

Tags: support, bumping

I have a question that I think should be good enough but it's now buried far down the list. I have read that editing it, changing the tags etc. should bump it (and I understand that this should not be overused) but that doesn't seem to work. Anyone else have similar problems?

Here's the question: [Hodge dual on orthonormal basis: two inconsistent answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225106/hodge-dual-on-orthonormal-basis-two-inconsistent-answers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Bumping only pushes it up on the [front page](http://math.stackexchange.com), and not on the [Questions page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions).
2. The effect of edit w.r.t. bumping is not immediate, there is a few minute delay (I assume due to database propagation and stuff on the back-end).

Answer (score 3):

The question has been bumped, and has received two answers.